# Posting SESSION variables, that have been collected from mysql database, to a new page

Tags: php, mysql, session, post

I have been working on this for the last several days. What I want the code to achieve; Have a page displaying a certain number of abbreviated blog articles. I then want to have a link at the bottom of the blog that links to the whole article. I also want a link on the full story page that can return you to the list of abbreviated stories. I have tried to achieve this using SESSION id and pretty much have everything working except for one major thing. When the display page for the entire blog is shown it cuts off at an apostrophe or any other html special character. I have tried to use the htmlspecialchars... but I just cant figure it out. Please help.

I have attached the three pages below that I have been using.
    1) The code to retrieve the info
    2) the page that runs the loop and displays the abbreviated results
    3) the full story page that shows entire blog article

PAGE ONE

```
/*$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)                                          
        or die("Couldn't execute query, Retard.");*/




// find out how many rows are in the table 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ashly";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) 
or die("Could not connect, Dickhead");
$r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$_SESSION['numrows'] = $r[0];
##JH echo "{$_SESSION['numrows']} <br/><br>";

// number of rows to show per page
$_SESSION['rowsperpage'] = 4;

// find out total pages
$_SESSION['totalpages'] = ceil($_SESSION['numrows'] / $_SESSION['rowsperpage']);
##JH echo $_SESSION['totalpages'];

//   get the current page or set a default

//if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
if (isset($_POST['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_POST['currentpage'])) {
// cast var as int
  $_POST['currentpage'] = (int) $_POST['currentpage'];
} else {
// default page num
$_POST['currentpage'] = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($_POST['currentpage'] > $_SESSION['totalpages']) {
// set current page to last page
$_POST['currentpage'] = $_SESSION['totalpages'];
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($_POST['currentpage'] < 1) {
// set current page to first page
$_POST['currentpage'] = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$_SESSION['offset'] = ($_POST['currentpage'] - 1) * $_SESSION['rowsperpage'];

// get the info from the db 
$sql = " SELECT * FROM ashly ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 
{$_SESSION['offset']},       {$_SESSION['rowsperpage']} ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Could not connect, connection Error");


// while there are rows to be fetched...


/*** this is where testPagingSESSION.inc goes. Has all loop and and page links 
in    it****/

##JH was: commented out for TESTING include("ashlyBlog2.inc"); 
                                include("ashlyBlogTESTING.inc");  // this include 
uses    the character control function
                                ?>
```

PAGE TWO: loop to display blog list

```
     <?php


                 while ($_SESSION['list'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                 extract($_SESSION['list']);
                 $price = number_format($price,2);
                 $timeDisplay = $_SESSION['list'];

          $_SESSION['blog'] = $blog;
          $_SESSION['time'] = date("F j, Y ", strtotime($time));      
          $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
         // $_SESSION['blog']=  htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['blog']);
         // $_SESSION['title']= htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['title']);


          $position=35; // Define how many characters you want to display.

$message= $_SESSION['blog']; 
$post = substr($message,$position,1); // Find what is the last character 
                                        displaying.
       We find it by getting only last one character from your display message.

if($post !=" "){ // In this step, if last character is not " "(space) do this step .

// Find until we found that last character is " "(space) 
// by $position+1 (14+1=15, 15+1=16 until we found " "(space) that mean character 20) 
while($post !=" "){
$i=1;
$position=$position+$i;

$message= $_SESSION['blog']; 
$post = substr($message,$position,1); 
}

}

$post = substr($message,0,$position); // Display your message
//echo $post;
//echo "...";
 $_SESSION['title'] = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['title']);

          echo "

    <h3 class='blog'>{$_SESSION['title']}</h3>
    <p class='date' ><b>{$_SESSION['time']}</b></p>
    <p class='blog'>$post....</p>



            <form action='ashlyBlogBig2.php' method='POST'> 
                           <input type='hidden' 
            name='title'   value='{$_SESSION['title']}'/>
                           <input type='hidden' 
            name='time' value='{$_SESSION['time']}'/>
                           <input type='hidden' 
            name='blog' value='{$_SESSION['blog']}'/>
                   <input type='submit' name='to you' 
            class='productButtons' value='Read On. . . .'>
                  </form> ";
     }//end while loop

?>



     <?php
/******  build the pagination links ******/

// range of num links to show
$_SESSION['range'] = 3;

// start table for page buttons
echo "<table class='pagingTable' cell-padding='0' cell-spacing='0'>
    <tr>";
// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($_POST['currentpage'] > 1) {

 // get previous page num
  $_SESSION['prevpage'] = ($_POST['currentpage'] - 1);

 // show < link to go back to 1 page
       echo "<td><form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='currentpage' value='{$_SESSION['prevpage']}'/>   
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='prevPage' value='&nbsp;' />
      </form></td>";

} // end if 


// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($_SESSION['x'] = ($_POST['currentpage'] - $_SESSION['range']); 
 $_SESSION['x'] < (($_POST['currentpage'] +
  $_SESSION['range']) + 1); $_SESSION['x']++) 
   {
// if it's a valid page number...
if (($_SESSION['x'] > 0) && ($_SESSION['x'] <= $_SESSION['totalpages'])) {
  // if we're on current page...
  if ($_SESSION['x'] == $_POST['currentpage']) {
     // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
     echo " <td class='active'><b>{$_SESSION['x']}</b></td> ";
  // if not current page...
  } else {
     // make it a link

  echo "<td><form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='POST'>
       <input type='hidden' name='currentpage' value='{$_SESSION['x']}' />
       <input type='submit' name='submit' 
       class='productPaging'    value='{$_SESSION['x']}'/>
      </form></td>";

    } // end else
  } // end if 
 } // end for

 // if not on last page, show forward and last page links


 if ($_POST['currentpage'] != $_SESSION['totalpages']) 
 {
  $_SESSION['nextpage'] = ($_POST['currentpage'] + 1); 


 // echo forward link for next page
 echo " <td><form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='currentpage' value='{$_SESSION['nextpage']}'/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='nextPage' value='&nbsp;' />
      </form></td>";


 }
 echo "</tr></table>"; // close table

// echo forward link for lastpage
?>
```

PAGE THREE: whole blog article display

```
 <?php

              ## These top four variable are commented out, tried but didn't work                
                  ##JH$_POST['title'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST[title])) ; 
                  ##JH$_POST['blog'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST[blog])) ;
                  ##$_POST['title']= htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
                  ##$_POST['blog']= htmlspecialchars($_POST['blog']);

                  //$_POST['blog'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_POST[blog]);

                   echo" 

    <h3 class='blog'>{$_POST['title']}</h3>
    <p class='date' ><b>{$_POST['time']}</b></p>
    <p class='blog'>{$_POST['blog']}</p>";


                   ?>



        </div>   <!-- end bigProduct -->

           <br/><br/>
                    <span class="backCategory"><center>
                    <b>
                       <a href=
                    "http://www.affiliate-marketing-abc.com/bagelmania/
                       ashlyBlog2.php"> Back to Category</a>
                    </b></center></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: (you have two identically qoutation mark in echos, first at your class, secound in you session)

```
<h3 class='blog'>{$_SESSION['title']}</h3>
```

Solution 1:

```
<h3 class=\'blog\'>{$_SESSION['title']}</h3>
```

Solution 2:

use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function